# Performance differences between bwlabeln on Matlab and skimage.measure.label on Python?

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-image

I'm currently in the process of converting a Matlab program that performs image analysis into Python. One of the specific parts of the program utilizes bwlabeln to label the various components in a 3D matrix with sequentially increasing labels. I was able to find a very similar function in the skimage.measure package called label which essentially does the exact same thing. However, I find that when using input matrices of the same size and data type between both programs, bwlabeln on Matlab runs significantly faster (almost 4 times faster) than label in Python.

I was wondering what the reason is for this and if there is any way to speed up the Python code or improve performance?

On both functions, I am using 26 - connected neighborhoods which both seem to do by default but I further specified as an argument just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the scikit-image algorithm is able to label arrays of integers, ie with more values than 0 and 1. Therefore, it is a different algorithm than the Matlab algorithm which is restricted to only 0 and 1 (False and True). You can use the `label` algorithm from `scipy.ndimage` which is indeed 4x faster on the binary image defined below, so you should be able to match up Matlab's speed with this function.

```py
In [1]: from scipy import ndimage                                               

In [2]: from skimage import measure                                             

In [3]: from skimage import data                                                                                             

In [5]: img = data.binary_blobs(length=256, blob_size_fraction=0.25, n_dim=3)   

In [6]: %timeit labels = ndimage.label(img)                                     
161 ms ± 2.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit labels = measure.label(img)                                     
629 ms ± 6.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```